# Cannot map raw SQL query to DataRow

Tags: linq, entity-framework, datarow

I am trying to get IEnumerable from linq query below. What am I doing wrong?

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> results = 
    context.Database.SqlQuery<DataRow>("SELECT * FROM Customer").AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: What happens when you execute the code? Do you see any exceptions? Unexpected results?

Answer (score 3):

`DataRow` class does not have default (parameterless) constructor, so you can't use it as query parameter type. There is no generic constraints on type parameter, and nothing mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)(!), but column map factory will throw exception if parameter type does not have default constructor:

> The result type 'System.Data.DataRow' may not be abstract and must
>   include a default constructor.

Here is a code which throws this exception:

```
internal static CollectionColumnMap CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndClrType(
    DbDataReader reader, Type type, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
{
      BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
      ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(flags, (Binder) null, Type.EmptyTypes, (ParameterModifier[]) null);
      if (type.IsAbstract || (ConstructorInfo) null == constructor && !type.IsValueType)
          throw EntityUtil.InvalidOperation(InvalidTypeForStoreQuery((object) type));
      // ...
}
```

**BTW** Mapping to DataRow makes no sense, even if it would have default public constructor. Because it is not simple primitive type and it does not have properties which match the names of columns returned from the query (yes, mapping uses properties only).

Correct usage of Linq will be

```
IEnumerable<Customer> results = context.Customers;
```

That will generate `SELECT * FROM Customer` query, and map query results to customer entities. If you really want to use raw SQL:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> results = 
     context.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("SELECT * FROM Customers");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we were trying to solve the same problem (Google led me here, anyway). I am executing a raw SQL command through [`SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and wanted to assert individual properties of the results returned from the query in a unit test.

I called the method:

```
var result = (db.SqlQuery<Customer>("select * from customers").First();
```

and verified the data it returned:

```
Assert.AreEqual("John", result.FirstName);
```

I defined a private class `Customer` inside my test class (unfortunately, I'm not using Entity Framework):

```
private class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

The properties of Customer must match the column names returned in the SQL query, and they must be properties (not just variables of the `Customer` class. You don't have to create properties for all of the columns returned from the query.